# Product of all primes less then x

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

How to prove that $\prod_{p\leqslant{x}}p\leqslant4^{x-1},\ \forall x\geqslant2$,
 where product is taken over all prime numbers $p\leqslant{x}$

Comment: this MO [link](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10496/an-inequality-relating-the-factorial-to-the-primorial) could help,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One proof of this fact is the proof of Claim 2.2 of [these notes on Erdos' proof of Bertrand's postulate](http://nd.edu/~dgalvin1/pdf/bertrand.pdf) by David Galvin.